# broken links from news with internal link to page which is hidden in default language

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, tx-news

I have news articles of type `internal link`. The article is created in the default language and is localized. In the news article the internal link points to a page which has the `Hide default translation of page` flag set.

Now the editors have used the news plugin with `list of selected items`. In the default language they picked the above mentioned articles of type `internal link`. Now TYPO3 generates a broken link to the page in the default language which is hidden.

Is there any way to prevent the link being generated in this setup?

Expected behaviour would be that TYPO3 / tx_news renders the link only when the target page is available.

My setup:

- TYPO3 8.7.13
- tx_news 6.3.0

Answer (score 1):

Georg Ringer has fixed the problem: https://github.com/georgringer/news/commit/b7d49dd95f8dbc58fdec452f31b57935e5769549

The fix will be part of the next release of EXT:news.

Thx a lot to Georg for the fast fix!

Comment: Seems that the problem is rather TYPO3 core related: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/85063